# How to access the function property of a javascript object using variable

Tags: javascript, function, properties

Hi consider below code

```
 let test={
    a:function(){
      console.log('Hi')
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to invoke property 'a' using a variable ?

**This works ,**

```
 let test={
    a:function(tmp){
      console.log(tmp)
    }
  }
let functn='a';  
test[functn]("hello");
```

**but is there anyway to invoke the same like below code :**

```
 let test={
    a:function(){
      console.log('Hi')
    }
  }
let functn='a("hello")';  
test.function;
```

**The actual use case:**

This is protractor system test related question,

I have a parent object with css locator [id=1] and the child elements has the locators [id=1]>div , [id=1]>span etc.

so currently parent element is stored as

```
let parent = element(by.css('[id=1']) ,
```

child as

```
let child1= element(by.css('[div]')
```

So to find all child elements of the parent element the function is :

```
element(by.css('[id=1']).element(by.css('[div]')
```

so instead of writing the locator again, i want to achieve:

```
parent.child1
```

Comment: `b = test.a; b()`? Though this won't work, if the method contains `this` keyword.

Comment: You mean like `const fnct = {name: "a", args: ["hello"]}`? With that, you can do `test[fnct.name].apply(null, fnct.args)`. But no, `a("hello");` will never work.

Comment: @Bergi i updated the code , 'a("hello")'

Comment: So you want to executed a piece of JavaScript that is inside a string? Why? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve by doing it like that?

Comment: hi this protractor test related , i have a parent object with css locator [id=1] and the child elements are [id=1]>div , [id=1]>span etc. so currently parent element is stored as let parent = element(by.css('[id=1'])  , child as let child1= element(by.css('[div]')

Comment: @tsst In that case, sure, parse the string into the method name and the argument values, then use the above code

Comment: so to find child element the function is ,  element(by.css('[id=1']).element(by.css('[div]'). So, want to call it as parent.child1 instead of giving the locators again

Comment: does `element` implement a fluent interface? what is this function doing? and what do you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Was able to make it work, i am converting everything to string and calling it using eval function:**

```js
     let test={
        a:function(tmp){
          document.write(tmp)
        }
      }
    let functn='a("hello")';
    eval(Object.keys({test})[0]+'.'+functn)
```

Answer (score 1):

> This works ,

Yes, it does. Do that.

> but is there anyway to invoke the same like below code :

No.

`let functn=a("hello");` calls the function in the variable `a` and assigns its return value to `functn`.

Assuming that doesn't fail (because `a` isn't declared), then `test.function` looks at the value of the property named `function` (which has nothing to do with the variable `function` you just declared) on the object stored in `test` and does nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is and simpler form of the code

```js
// Using Function Arrow
let test = (message => 'Hello World!')()

console.log(test)

// Using factory function

let data = function() {
    return {
        nome:'Jack'
    }
}

console.log(data())
console.log(Object.values(data()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are looking for a currying solution:

```js
 let test={
    a:function(str){
      return () => console.log(str)
    }
  }
let functn=test.a("hello");  
functn();
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you are passing a string which is not neccessary if you dont accept any parameters.
What you can do is using **getters**.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

```
let test={
   get a (){
     console.log('Hi')
   }
}
```

So every time you are trying to access **a** it will be executed and so will print you 'Hi' in your console.

```
test.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your approach to one without using `eval` by taking an array of key and parameter and a function which take the key and parameter and calls the function of the object.

```js
let call = ([key, parameter]) => test[key](parameter),
    test = {
        a: function(tmp) { console.log(tmp); }
    },
    parameters = ['a', 'hello'];

call(parameters);
```